# Set attribute on multiple selectors

Tags: javascript

I'm trying the following, which doesn't work, but am wondering if there is something similar?

Basically, I'm trying to set the same attribute on multiple elements:

```
document.querySelectorAll("#id1, #id2, #id3").setAttribute('onclick','return false;');
```

I'm using vanilla Javascript, no library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`querySelectorAll()` will return an array-like node list that you need to loop through:

```
var elems = document.querySelectorAll("#id1, #id2, #id3");
for(var i = 0; i < elems.length; i ++){
    elems[i].setAttribute('onclick', 'return false');
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/jkuferwh/)

Answer (score 2):

There are several approaches for this, the most basic one is to iterate the set and add click handlers (In your case, you want an `addEventHandler` not an attribute!)

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll("#id1, #id2, #id3");
[].forEach.call(elements, function addClickHandler(el) {
    el.addEventListener('click', function() { return false; });
};
```

Perhaps a better approach if you have many elements is to set one event handler on the document, and see if it matches a query selector:

```
var elements = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("#id1, #id2, #id3")); //Turn into an array
document.addEventHandler('click', function(e) {
    if (elements.indexOf(e.target) !== -1) { //Element in list was clicked!
        return false;
    }
};
```