# Set the same attributes to selected elements javascipt

Tags: javascript

My code:

```
const useElem = [];
for (var a = 1; a <= 24; ++a) {
    useElem[a] = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'use');
}
useElem[1].setAttribute( 'class', 'normal');
useElem[2].setAttribute( 'class', 'normal');
useElem[1].setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink', 'xlink:href', url_normal_1);
useElem[2].setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink', 'xlink:href', url_normal_2);
useElem[3].setAttribute( 'class', 'hover');
useElem[4].setAttribute( 'class', 'hover'); 
useElem[3].setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink', 'xlink:href', url_hover_1);
useElem[4].setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink', 'xlink:href', url_hover_2);   
useElem[5].setAttribute( 'class', 'active');
useElem[6].setAttribute( 'class', 'active');    
useElem[5].setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink', 'xlink:href', url_active_1);
useElem[6].setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink', 'xlink:href', url_active_2);
.......
```

Is it possible to set the same attributes to multiple elements in more effective way?

Something like:

```
useElem[1,2].setAttribute( 'class', 'normal');
```

Comment: you could make more use of loops

Comment: That's what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: Why? You already have a loop you can use for your purposes

Comment: Great appreciation for more detail

Comment: @Serg why do you want to avoid loops? It should result in less repetition.

Comment: You have a loop `for (var a =1; a <= 24; ++a) {useElem[a] = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'use');}`
Why not use it to set attributes?

Comment: Post updated. As you can see the only certain pairs of elements have the same attributes.Each other pairs have different similar attributes.

Comment: Maybe this will help? [Set attribute on multiple selectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27127930/set-attribute-on-multiple-selectors)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a lot of way to lessen code repetition, eg you could also use a helper function if you don't want to use "loops":

```
function createElement(clas, url) {
  const el = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "use");
  el.setAttribute("class", clas);
  el.setAttributeNS("http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink", "xlink:href", url);
  return el;
}

const useElem = [
    null, // to start arrays at 1 O_o
    createElement('normal', url_normal_1),
    createElement('normal', url_normal_2),
    createElement('hover', url_hover_1),
    createElement('hover', url_hover_2),
    createElement('active', url_active_1),
    createElement('active', url_active_2),
    // ...
]
```